# Page numbering at bottom of page

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I am writing my thesis and I am using document class `thesis`. I want the page numbering appearing at bottom of the pages and centered.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, oneside, bold]{thesis}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
My text....
\end{document}
```

I tried writing something like that:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, oneside, bold]{thesis}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}

\begin{document}
    My text
\end{document}
```

But nothing is working. Any suggestions please.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: In your second example you have to call `\pagestyle{fancy}` to activate the page style provided by fancyhdr.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The package `fancyhdr` allows you the modification of the header. However the package `fancyhdr` doesn't overwrite the default styles instead it defines a new one named `fancy`. So you have to use `\pagestyle{fancy}`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, oneside, bold]{thesis}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}    
\begin{document}
    My text
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is a simpler method here: just write `\pagestyle{plain}` in the header https://stackoverflow.com/a/12653885/952234 .

Comment: However, your method works with `poemscol` package.

Comment: @Yaroslav, your solution seems better to me. It is simpler and doesn't give unnecessary header and footer lines. Thanks!

Comment: @YaroslavNikitenko you should write this as an answer. Is far more efficient!

Comment: @deps_stats done, thanks to you and Amazeunmb (can't notify twice).

Answer (score 3):

Write in the header or body

```
\pagestyle{plain}
```

The \pagestyle command changes the style from the current page on throughout the remainder of your document.

The [valid options](http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex_129.html) are:

- plain - Just a plain page number.
- empty - Produces empty heads and feet - no page numbers.
- headings - Puts running headings on each page. The document style specifies what goes in the headings.
- myheadings - You specify what is to go in the heading with the \markboth or the \markright commands.

Pro: doesn't require additional packages.

Con: the author of the question actually used *fancyhdr* (I don't know the reason). Several people pointed that my answer in comments would be also useful, that is why I'm posting it here.

See more about page styles and *fancyhdr* in the Wikibook on [LaTeX](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Customizing_Page_Headers_and_Footers).