# Numbering pages at the bottom

Tags: page-numbering, thesis

I am writing a `thesis` `documentclass`.

I get a line at the top, the chapter title and the even page number at the top of each page. I would like the page number to be at the bottom of the page, without deleting the chapter title from the header like it does with the `fancy`package the way I found it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117402/page-numbering-at-bottom-of-page).

Is it possible?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, twoside, bold]{thesis}

%\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
%\fancyhf{}
%\cfoot{\thepage}
%\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec cursus egestas nisl, ac tristique lorem fermentum et. In interdum massa quis odio dictum, quis sagittis felis aliquet. In viverra diam massa, eget porta ante ullamcorper vitae. Curabitur non velit mattis, scelerisque neque ut, porttitor enim. Phasellus id ipsum ipsum. Duis nec nisi sem. Duis consequat, quam eu fermentum tempor, lacus sem commodo mi, eu aliquam risus nunc et nisl.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Where's the `thesis.cls` you're using available? There are hundreds of them around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the entire setting using only `fancyhdr`. I have chosen the font shape and size of header and footer according to that of `thesis` class.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, twoside, bold]{thesis}
\setlength\headheight{15pt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[CE]{\small\slshape\leftmark}
\fancyhead[CO]{\small\slshape\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\small\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Preface}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
\markboth{Preface}{}
Some preface
\mainmatter
\chapter{Test}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec cursus egestas nisl, ac tristique lorem fermentum et. In interdum massa quis odio dictum, quis sagittis felis aliquet. In viverra diam massa, eget porta ante ullamcorper vitae. Curabitur non velit mattis, scelerisque neque ut, porttitor enim. Phasellus id ipsum ipsum. Duis nec nisi sem. Duis consequat, quam eu fermentum tempor, lacus sem commodo mi, eu aliquam risus nunc et nisl.
\clearpage
Some text
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works, but I get `contents` twice, one flushed right and one flushed left, in the header

Comment: @rickratti See the updated answer.

Comment: This is what I wanted, thank you! There is one issue though.
I added this to my `main` text. I get the `toc`, the next page shows "contents" and that's perfect. But the following page is 
`\chapter*{Preface}` with `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}` so it appears in the `toc` without a number. But it is not considered in the header, and I still get "Contents".
How do I get every chapter title to appear there?

Comment: @rickratti: Add `\markboth{Preface}{}` too. See the update.